# How to remove a XML node?

Tags: javascript, xml, pdf, xpath, xfa

I have some troubles in development of Acrobat. I use a XML file in a PDF and I read and write data. I can use XPath to search the data I want by some conditions. But I can't remove a node. I've read Acrobat Developer Guide and its API. found a method but which is not what i need .Let's list an example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfa:data xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">    
      <mapData>
         <busline>
                <name>first</name>
                <stationList>
                     <station>
                         <name>f1</name>
                     <station>
                         <name>f2</name>
                </stationList>
           </busline>      
           <busline>
                <name>second</name>
                <stationList>
                     <station>
                         <name>s1</name>
                     <station>
                         <name>s2</name>
                </stationList>
          </busline>
    </mapData>
</xfa:data>
```

Now I want to remove a busline node which its name is "second". How can I remove it? I found a method in API just like:

```
var root = XMLData.applyXPath(mapXML,"//mapData");  //mapXML is this XML file's XFAObject by parse method
var deleteNode = XMLData.applyXPath(mapXML,"//mapData/busline[name='first']");
root.remove(root.namedItem(deleteNode);    //it will delete all the busline nodes!!!
```

I also tried `root.nodes.remove(deleteNode.nodes.item(0));` still doesn't work.......

I tried some other ways but doesn't work , So i come to you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
deleteItemAt
```

Comment: deleteItemAt:  Deletes an item in a combobox or a listbox/r I'm not delete in field form,but in XML file,delete XML node